# Is it possible to render an object just with the normal map?

Tags: rendering, shaders

When an object with a normal map is rendered, there are always artifacts of the polygons of the original model on the outline of the model. Is there a way to make them invisible?
Here is what I mean -

- What I get (notice the outline) - 
  [image]
- What I'm aiming for (notice the outline) - 
  [image]

I think that this would impossible because if the outline polygons were invisible, the model itself would be invisible. 
Any ideas?

Question Update: I thought of this idea because when a model with normal map is rotated, the outlining polygons are not shaded by the map. I was thinking of making that area invisible. Is it possible?
Here is a render with more extreme example to show what I mean - 
[image]

Comment: I don't think this is possible. There's no true substitute for high-poly details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A normal map will allow to simulate high poly details on a low poly mesh (using light) but won't change the shape of it. You won't be able to remove the visibility of the topology on borders with good result. You can try a fresnel or layer weight node to mix a transparent but this will make holes. This could work on a volume but not on a surface shader.

All you can really do is adding a subsurf to add some topo and smooth the borders.